# Why does my UEFI time jump ahead 3 hours on every boot?

Tags: windows-10, uefi, kubuntu

Whenever I reboot my pc, the motherboard UEFI time jumps ahead exactly 3 hours. Here are my PC specs and other things.

My PC is about a year old.

I Dualboot:

- Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit
- Kubuntu (Linux) 20.10

My PC Specs:

- AMD Ryzen 5 2600x Six Core Processor.
- 16GB Ram
- Motherboard: ASRock b450m Pro4
- GPU: Radeon RX 570 Series
- and 1 Samsung 500gb m.2 and a 250gb Kingston SSD.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it after you reboot from Windows to Linux, or Linux to Windows, or Linux to Linux, or Windows to Windows, or all of the above? What are the contents of `/etc/adjtime` on Linux? What is the output of `reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation /v RealTimeIsUniversal` on Windows?

Comment: Its after I reboot from Linux. The output of the windows command is `ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.`

Comment: Please provide the output of `timedatectl` on Kubuntu, if possible. [Put it in your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1637876/edit), using a code block.

Answer (score 2):

This is typical in a dual-boot Linux/Windows situation.

You have the time-settings in Linux incorrectly configured.
Windows always stores "local time" in the CMOS clock.
Linux, by default, uses UTC time. You need to change that so Linux uses "local time" as well. The setting is usually called "RTC uses UTC" or something similar.

If you don't you will see this behavior when you switch OS. Each OS will sync the local clock to a time-server from the internet (or manual setting you make) and than write the value back to the CMOS clock, but they do it with different offsets (Windows "as is" and Linux in UTC).

Please note: The error message you mention in the comments probably has nothing to do with the jumping clock at all, but has a different reason.

Comment: Living in a territory where DST adjustments still happen, I'd really recommend the opposite - [making both systems use UTC time instead.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_time#UTC_in_Windows)

Comment: So should I change my linux clock? It is at the right time when I boot it, and It is automatically synced to EST (my timezone) through the internet, just like windows.

Comment: @texxte: No, this is about changing the relationship *between* the UEFI clock and the Linux (or Windows) clock.